# How to create an outlook calendar event in laravel?

Tags: outlook, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, office365, outlook-calendar

I would be so glad if anyone could answer my question.
I'm developing a meeting scheduler in laravel 5, the good news is that i can get the events from the calendar, i've been following this tutorial: https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/php.

The main issue is that i can't create an event. I've seen some tutorials that mention about sending a ics file through an email, but this don't work.is there a way to create an event from a php script??? If anyone had working with outlook calendar API for php, please give me some recommendation. Have a nice day

Comment: Are you trying to work with Outlook on the desktop (no matter what email server the person is connected to), an Exchange email server either on premise or online (what most companies using Outlook connect to), or specifically an Exchange server hosted by Microsoft in the Cloud through Office Online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way of integrating your app with Office 365 is to use the new Graph API, this is the new unified endpoint for all Office 365 services.

You can find more about that here http://graph.microsoft.io.

On that site is the complete documentation on what to send with the request to create a event in the users calendar, it's just plain JSON.

You just need to make sure that you've got the right permissions for the app, to actually write to the users calendar.

You can find a demo here, https://github.com/OfficeDev?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=o365-PHP-microsoft-graph, that shows how to connect your php app to the Graph API, the SDK is not ready yet, so you need to write your own request for now.

Comment: thank you for your recommendation but... can i register my app without using azure????. I see that is a paid service

Comment: No, you need to register your app with an Azure Active Directory, but that is free on the entry level plan. Check out this website, azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory, it will show you the different prices.

Comment: If the answer helped you out, then please accept it. This will make it easier for other people to find the right solution.